# Controlling simultaneous inserts into Cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have event messages arriving over iot hub and being processed by an Azure Function. For every CREATE event, I want an entry in Cosmos (SQL API) that can be appended to later. Periodically, the iot devices will malfunction and send two CREATE events within a millisecond or two of one another.

Due to the scale, there will be multiple instances of the Azure Functions running. If two different instances pick up these simultaneous events, two items will be created in Cosmos. The functions first check that the entry already exists in Cosmos and if not, insert it, but this is done on the server side, not within the database so is not guaranteed to be accurate. GUIDs are used as the Id. A synthetic id comprised of fields that make this unique would have to include the time, which isn't desirable right now.

Would a stored procedure solve this? Can the stored procedures in Cosmos lock the appropriate partition so that it has sole access?

Comment: No, sprocs don't lock partitions. If the event has a unique identifier that is repeated in both CREATE requests, would a Unique Key Index help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta In this case, the two messages are identical aside from (maybe) one millisecond difference in the timestamp. If I understand correctly, the Unique Key would need to incorporate the timestamp for valid messages to work? I thought of adding the time rounded to the minute as the Unique Key, could still happen if the two malfunctioning messages are sent at the wrong time.

Comment: Unique Key would have helped if the message had some unique property (not the id) that would identify it. Seems like it wouldn't apply in your case sadly.

Comment: Typically, IoT-sourced messages have some unique id in the payload. Do these messages have such an id? If so, you can incorporate that id into your strategy. Otherwise: even with a single instance of an Azure Function, and even if all data was ingested serially, how would you know that you have a duplicate message from the IoT device?

Comment: @DavidMakogon Unfortunately these do not. The device will send a CREATE, then N number of events then an END. I know it's a duplicate because I'll receive two CREATES in a row. I can determine later, programmatically, that this problem has occurred, just hoping to find a way to prevent it in the first place.

Comment: For clarity there is a unique id per device, but not a unique id per message.

Comment: Just to add here. Having your Azure Function first check if the item is already in Cosmos is at best marginally helpful as an item could get inserted between the call to check it's existence and any subsequent/duplicate insert. As suggested above, you need something unique within the message itself sent from whatever generates the message in the payload before arriving at IoT Hubs.